# Lotus Domino Designer import 3rd party jar file

Tags: java, lotus-notes, icalendar

I'm developing custom Agent for LotusNotes 8.5.

I'd like to use iCal4j jar to convert Calendar issue to ICS format.

Question is: how to import coresponding jar in Lotus Agent ??

Now is written when compile: package 'net.fortuna.ical4j.model' does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include jar files in your Notes agent by clicking **Edit project..** in the bottom left corner of the agent window. Check the `Archives` checkbox to see .jar files.

Here's an example: [Developing an IBM Lotus Domino agent with JMS](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-jms/index.html#N101CF)

Comment: Note that some third party JARs don't play nice with the way Notes / Domino stores them within an agent project (e.g. some Apache stuff, anything that uses reflection). In these instances, you're better off adding the jar file to your Domino server's classpath (ext directory, or explicitly declare the classpath in the server's JavaUserClasses ini file).